# What is the most efficient way to whitelist utf-8 characters in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, security, utf-8, whitelist

My goal is to protect my web site from attacks by creating a strict whitelist of allowed characters for any and all POST data recieved from the client side.

This is a piece of cake when staying within ASCII characters. Something like:

```
if(preg_match('/[^aA-zZ0-9]/', $stringToTest))
{
   // Battle stations!!
}
```

However, I need to be able to allow any and all utf-8 characters, especially asian character sets like Japanese, Chinese, and Korean. But I don't want to exclude anybody with wacky characters, like Arabic or Russian, or whatever. One world, one love! ;)

How can I allow people to input the characters of their native language while excluding the nasties used in evil scripts, like *, ?, angle brackets, and so on?

Comment: I think this kind of GET/POST validation is dumb. If you want to disallow HTML, use `htmlspecialchars()` to escape it. If you want to allow HTML but without dangerous thing like scripts, use a HTML parser which removes or rejects bad things instead of writing something own which is not only likely to miss something but also much less comfortable. Blacklisting characters from a certain language is clearly bad unless you actually want to piss off users using this language. However, whitelist regexps like in your question are actually useful for things like username validation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\w` will give you word characters (letters, digits, and underscores), which is probably what you're after `\s` for whitespace.

e.g.

```
if(preg_match('/[\w\s]/', $stringToTest))
{
   // Battle stations!!
}
```

[regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) is an excellent reference for this stuff - [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html) and [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refunicode.html) are a couple of relevant pages :)

edit: some more clarification needed, sorry!

here's what I usually use for CJK:

```
function get_CJK_ranges() {

    return array(
                "[\x{2E80}-\x{2EFF}]",      # CJK Radicals Supplement
                "[\x{2F00}-\x{2FDF}]",      # Kangxi Radicals
                "[\x{2FF0}-\x{2FFF}]",      # Ideographic Description Characters
                "[\x{3000}-\x{303F}]",      # CJK Symbols and Punctuation
                "[\x{3040}-\x{309F}]",      # Hiragana
                "[\x{30A0}-\x{30FF}]",      # Katakana
                "[\x{3100}-\x{312F}]",      # Bopomofo
                "[\x{3130}-\x{318F}]",      # Hangul Compatibility Jamo
                "[\x{3190}-\x{319F}]",      # Kanbun
                "[\x{31A0}-\x{31BF}]",      # Bopomofo Extended
                "[\x{31F0}-\x{31FF}]",      # Katakana Phonetic Extensions
                "[\x{3200}-\x{32FF}]",      # Enclosed CJK Letters and Months
                "[\x{3300}-\x{33FF}]",      # CJK Compatibility
                "[\x{3400}-\x{4DBF}]",      # CJK Unified Ideographs Extension A
                "[\x{4DC0}-\x{4DFF}]",      # Yijing Hexagram Symbols
                "[\x{4E00}-\x{9FFF}]",      # CJK Unified Ideographs
                "[\x{A000}-\x{A48F}]",      # Yi Syllables
                "[\x{A490}-\x{A4CF}]",      # Yi Radicals
                "[\x{AC00}-\x{D7AF}]",      # Hangul Syllables
                "[\x{F900}-\x{FAFF}]",      # CJK Compatibility Ideographs
                "[\x{FE30}-\x{FE4F}]",      # CJK Compatibility Forms
                "[\x{1D300}-\x{1D35F}]",    # Tai Xuan Jing Symbols
                "[\x{20000}-\x{2A6DF}]",    # CJK Unified Ideographs Extension B
                "[\x{2F800}-\x{2FA1F}]"     # CJK Compatibility Ideographs Supplement
    );

}

function contains_CJK($string) {
    $regex = '/'.implode('|',get_CJK_ranges()).'/u';
    return preg_match($regex,$string);
}
```

To get everything that's could be a problem for escaping and other black-hat stuff, use:

`/[^\p{Punctuation}]/` ( == `/[^\p{P}]/` )

or

`/[^\32-\151]/` ( == `/[^!-~]/` )

[another good link](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html)

Comment: Wow, that makes things real easy. Thanks for that!

Comment: I thought that \w was equivalent to [A-Za-z0-9_], so you should test to make sure this works. A good place to test is http://regexpal.com/

Comment: Yes, unfortunately after some more testing, this blocks any non-ASCII characters, such as Japanese and Chinese.

Comment: that's what those links were for... updated with more info :)

Comment: Cool. Thanks so much for all the information, and I went a little deeper into the links you nrovided. What I'm wondering now, though, is if I go the whitelist route, am I going to have to build this massive array of all possible languages to check for? And if I do, is that going to be a huge processing hit on the server to run through all of it to check each one?

Comment: the main reason to use regexes here is that they're fast with low overhead, and php will cache them automatically to save recompiling them every time, too.  That said, I'd just use `/[^\p{Punctuation}]/` or `/[^\32-\151]/` if I were you :)

Comment: Yes, I think I'm seeing the light with blacklisting punctuation instead of whitelisting everything else. Thank you for your advice!

Answer (score 2):

For some things you can base64 encode, but I've had to remove a tiny bit of functionality where that's not doable as keeping all characters seems more important and it's certainly not worth any more time right now.

...

After saying that I came across this but it seems the issue then becomes efficiency due to so many characters if you want a generic function but that isn't a huge issue (Chinese, Russian and Greek may have separate webpages etc.).

http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php.

Answer (score 0):

Try inverting the test - use a blacklist instead of a whitelist. e.g.

```
if(preg_match('/[\*\?<>]/', $stringToTest))
{
    // Battle stations!!
}
```

Regex might not be quite right, but you get the idea.

Comment: I thought about blacklisting, but I get nervous that I won't catch all the clever circumvention techniques the black hats use.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you can protect anything this way.
You will just complicate matters for the fair users, but don't stop malicious one.

I would just quit a site that won't allow me to enter a question mark or a quote, or e-mail.
Simple dot is among "nasties used in evil scripts" for sure. But any message without it would look ugly.

While SQL injection can be done using alphabet characters only.

I see no sense in such a "protection".